# Why does the Added Inter-Sentence Space Have No Stretch or Shrink?

Tags: spacing, tex-core

I'm looking at page 433 of the TeXbook with the list of `\fontdimen` parameters. So the interword space equals `\fontdimen2` plus `\fontdimen3` minus `\fontdimen4` where the latter two parameters are the interword stretch and interword shrink, respectively. But the extra space added at the end of a sentence equals just `\fontdimen7` The added inter-sentence spacing does not shrink or stretch is proportion to the stretch or shrink of the interword space. This is bad typography IMO (I am a novice I admit). I feel that the intersentence spacing should stretch or stretch in proportion to its increased size. For example, if the intersentence spacing of a font equals 1.33 times its interword spacing, then the total intersentence stretch/shrink should also equal 1.33 times the interword stretch/shrink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why" questions are impossible to answer unless you ask the code designer but what you suggest (multiplying all three components equally) would make end of sentence space have larger shrink than normal spaces, which could have some weird effects.

If `\spaceskip` and `\xspaceskip` are not set then

if *f* is the current space factor, the space used is

*f* =1000: `\fontdimen2` plus `\fontdimen3` minus `\fontdimen4`

*f* <2000: `\fontdimen2` plus (*f*/1000)`\fontdimen3` minus (1000/*f*)`\fontdimen4`

*f* ≥2000: (`\fontdimen2+\fontdimen7`) plus (*f*/1000)`\fontdimen3` minus (1000/*f*)`\fontdimen4`

which seems to work well enough in practice